# Date String with 'T' and 'Z' characters

Tags: date, momentjs

I am saving a Date in the sql database using the following format :

`Moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss', 'true')`

and when I retrieving the same from the db the dateString is coming as : `2020-09-15T20:05:28.000Z`; which in turns if I do `Moment('2020-09-15T20:05:28.000Z').format('ddd MMM DD GGGG, h:mm A')` if gives back `Wed Sep 16 2020, 1:35 AM` which actually not correct.

Can anyone throw a light on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time retrieved from DB is in UTC format, and you are parsing it in your local time

According to the [doc](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/)

> By default, moment parses and displays in local time.
>
> If you want to parse or display a moment in UTC

So if you want to display the as you expected, use `.utc` method

```js
let time = moment("2020-09-15T20:05:28.000Z")
  .utc()
  .format("ddd MMM DD GGGG, h:mm A")

console.log(time)
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `moment.utc("2020-09-15T20:05:28.000Z")` will work too.  But also, please read  https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/  Thanks.